# How do I set all of my Jade files to output application/xhtml+xml?

Tags: pug, express

I'm wanting to write XHTML5. How do I change the default mime type on my responses to `application/xhtml+xml`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Express, you can set the header before calling the template engine, like:

```
res.header('Content-Type', 'application/xhtml+xml'); 
res.render('index.jade', {
    title: "Welcome"
});
```

Comment: After you make a change, don't forget to refresh (Ctrl+F5) your browser to notice the change.